# Error when trying to out out data from a database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting the error shown here when trying to output things:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM colours.prompt_reply' at line 1

Please help

```
MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("select (user_Id, project, project_feedback, when) FROM colours.prompt_reply ;",conDataBase);
```

Comment: You can't just do `colours.prompt_reply`

Comment: Why are your select columns between "(" and ")"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have an error in your command

`MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("select user_Id, project, project_feedback, when FROM your_table_name",conDataBase);`

is the 'when' part of your table?

i haven't really used MySql in C# but i had used Sql Sever before i think it would work

Comment: Yes when is a column in my table .  when is a reserved word that why i was getting an error

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is not formatted properly,
Is "when" is a column name of your table ? If yes then

use below as

```
MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("select user_Id, project, project_feedback, `when` FROM colours.prompt_reply ;",conDataBase);
```

As `when` is a keyword in MySql so if you are using that as column name then use backticks.

Comment: @MkhululiCooperNcubeKamzilan : If this is what you are looking for and it's working then you should accept this as 'answer'.